# Does upgrading clip size increase how much ammo I can carry?

Tags: the-last-of-us

If I upgrade the clip size for a gun in *The Last of Us*, does that increase the maximum amount of ammunition I can carry for that weapon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/652686-the-last-of-us/66495504) GameFAQs post, upgrading your weapons clip capacity effectively increases its maximum ammo capacity by 1 bullet per upgrade

Comment: I can confirm upgrading clip size does upgrade ammo held, but only after you reload the gun.